# Can not access Vuex store object in the mounted hook

Tags: vue.js, vuex, hook

I need to use Vuex state in mounted hook. But when I call dispatch I get {__ob__: Observer} object which does not contain expected data. I dont understand. Mounted hook should have access to all resources including Vuex store.

```
async mounted() {
    this.newShareToken = this.$route.query.token;

    console.log('mounted this.checkLocalStorageToken()');
    if( !this.checkLocalStorageToken(this.newShareToken) ) {
       ...
    }
}

// This is the problem. 
checkLocalStorageToken(token) {
   return !!this.$store.dispatch('campaign-new-share/checkShareToken', token);
},
```

and here is the code from Vuex store

```
checkShareToken: ({state, commit}, token) => {
    console.log(state.share_tokens);  // This is not the value but {__ob__: Observer}
    return state.share_tokens[token] ? state.share_tokens[token] : null;
}
```

Comment: You are not returning any value from the vuex action, so how do you expect it to work in the `if` condition?

Comment: The code is simplyfied. There is a return value.             `return state.share_tokens[token] ? state.share_tokens[token] : null;`

Comment: what's the initial value that you have in `state.share_tokens`?

Comment: is the initial value `{}`?

Comment: Yes it is empty object {} But it should contain the value at the check point.

Comment: lol, how is that even possible, if in case you are doing any db hit and then assigning the `response value` to the state then you will be able to see that value in the `console` else you will be shown only the `empty object`